# When are mysql save a new binlog file?

Tags: java, mysql, spring, database, binlog

I'm developing 1 java application to reading a `binlog file` to catch query event.  Everything would be fine without exception. But what will happen if my application was crashed, i will miss many event to from my database. So i wondering when mysql save new bin log position in a new binlog file? So i can save a checkpoint so as not to miss any event from my database.

My external library use to read binlog mysql :

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.github.shyiko</groupId>
    <artifactId>mysql-binlog-connector-java</artifactId>
    <version>0.21.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Hi Thành Đặng, did you find a solution for this? 

I saw the accepted answer but that is more on the MySQL server end not on the Java app. Correct me if I have mistaken.

Comment: Hi Aush, thanks for your attendtion for my question. 
I use Java to read mysql binlogs. When my java application crashes and I restore it, it may still read the old log files again while mysql  append a new logs in a new file. Therefore, I want to ask when my sql saves new logs and files so that I can consider it as a condition so that when I restore the java application, it still works normally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MySQL opens a new binary log file in three cases:

- The current binary log file exceeds `max_binlog_size`. The file can go over that size slightly, to allow the current event to finish writing.
- Some client runs the command `FLUSH LOGS`. For example, mysqldump does this if you use the `--flush-logs` command option.
- The MySQL Server restarts.